# syntax error - JS - background.style.backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

This works and the image renders.

```
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(0.gif)';
```

This does not work and the image does not render at all.

```
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(0.gif) no-repeat center center fixed';
```

There is no error in the console.

What am I missing here? This should have worked. The second is syntactically correct, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `body.style.background` instead. The `body.style.backgroundImage` is just for the image.